# How can i validate date?

Tags: asp.net

In a page i have taken a textbox  used to enter date in mm/dd/yyyy formate.

I want that when user enter the incorrect format of the date then it show a message that incorrect format of date.

How can i validate textbox that only correct fomate of date can be entered by user.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Also you ca make use of regular expression vlidator which is bundeled with .net

Comment: @Devjosh: Thanks Devjosh but in this case what will be the validation expression?

Comment: you can find regex just google around just visit the following linkhttp://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) method.

```
DateTime dateValue;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy", 
      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of validating use calender control or there are loads of Jquery calenders, google it , Its better to provide user with date selection instead of date insertion. Make it idiot proof.

Comment: I think this shouldn't be instead of validating. Validation should be put in place whenever the user has free control to change the value of the textbox

Answer (score 2):

```
If Not IsDate(txtDate.Text) Then
   'Error message code here...
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `Date.TryParse()`.